# set -e -o pipefail not working because of make incompatibility

Tags: bash, make

I am attempting to run a bash script/makefile with the line

```
set -e -o pipefail
```

The makefile itself has the terse line that this doesn't appear to work with make 3.81, which is the version my Ubuntu install gives me.

(Running the script gives me: `set: Illegal option -o pipefail`)

Is there a way round this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `make` uses `/bin/sh` to run shell code so you can't run bash-specific commands.

Add the line

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
```

to make `make` use bash instead. See [the GNU make documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Choosing-the-Shell) for more about this.