# "set -e -o pipefail" not working on bash script on Ubuntu 16

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I've been trying to run on Ubuntu 16 a bash script that I developed on CentOS 7.

The first line of the script is:

```
set -o nounset -o pipefail -o errexit
```

When I try to run this script, I get the following error:

```
project.sh: 6: set: Illegal option -o pipefail
```

How to solve this issue?
I also the solution explain in the [answer to this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/805816/set-e-o-pipefail-not-working-because-of-make-incompatibility/805818) but it did not help (my file is not a `make`).

Comment: What is the shebang line in the script ? `#!/bin/sh` ?

Comment: Are you _sure_ that the script is run by Bash? Do you invoke it with `bash scriptname`, it the first line `#! /bin/bash`?

Comment: The first line is `#!/bin/sh`, but I was invoking it as `sh project.sh` as in CentOS! Now I tried to run `bash project.sh` and the problem disappeared! Thanks guys!

Comment: @DavideChicco.it see my answer. `sh` is symlink to `dash` shell on Ubuntu. Also, start changing your habits. Use `chmod +x script.sh` and `./script.sh` to run it.  The way you do it `sh ./script.sh` has whole lot of issues of its own and easy to mess up

Comment: If the command `bash project.sh` fixed your error, then you should change your shebang line to `#!/bin/bash` that way you don't have to type in the `bash` in front of your script name.

Answer (score 18):

On Ubuntu the default shell is `dash` (aka Debian Almquist Shell), to which `/bin/sh` is symlink. When your shell script is run with `#!/bin/sh`, you are effectively trying to run it with the default shell. However, `dash` doesn't have the `pipefail` option, which is why you're getting the error.

```
# Verifying what /bin/sh is symlinked to dash
$ ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 2月  17  2016 /bin/sh -> dash
# Verify that pipefail doesn't exist as option for dash
$ dash    
$ set -o | grep pipefail                                              
$ set -o pipefail
dash: 1: set: Illegal option -o pipefail
$ sh
$ set -o pipefail
sh: 1: set: Illegal option -o pipefail
# Try this same option in bash
$ bash --posix
bash-4.3$ set -o pipefail
bash-4.3$  
# no error
```

Comment: Just the command `set -o` will list all of the options supported by `set`.

Comment: @Terrance I know, I just wanted to reproduce the error specifically. Although, I'll add that one as well.

Comment: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure dash` then `No` to unset `dash` as default shell.

Comment: @Tuan I wouldn't do that. Although `bash` is made POSIX compliant and in theory everything should work just fine, there's a possibility that some system scripts might not work. Low but still a possibility

Comment: Thanks @SergiyKolodyazhnyy, just commented because I had the same issue and this command fixed mine.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy This makes a lot of sense (in my situation).  How do I "fix" a script that has the following line in it at the start (for usage in Ubuntu, as I believe the script was originally written for/in CentOS) and the instructions are to run the script with ./script [#!/bin/bash   set -e -o pipefail]

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for a simple script that circumvents the `dash` issue with Ubuntu, you can use

```
bash | set +o pipefail
```

Answer (score 0):

One more option that can cause this (or similar) issue: Windows line endings (CRLF, "\r\n") in script file.

Much more likely to occur on WSL than raw Ubuntu, but took me a while to find out.

Since line endings are wrong, interpreter reads the last argument exactly as `pipefail\r`, which is interpreted as unknown one. But `\r` is not visible in terminal, what makes hard to understand the cause.

The fix is to ensure that line endings in your text editor are set to LF.

Answer (score 0):

try to use below flag then it work. I have validated it.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e -o pipefail

# to reset use
# set +e +o pipefail
```