# How to fix "set -e -o pipefail" (CentOS script) for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: bash, scripts, sh, dash-shell

I'm working with a set of scripts that automate some bioinformatics (mitoVGP; https://github.com/VGP/vgp-assembly/tree/master/mitoVGP) and then the install is done as a conda environment.

The problem (sh symlinked to dash, as opposed to bash) has been outlined by @SergiyKolodyazhnyy in the first answer here: ["set -e -o pipefail" not working on bash script on Ubuntu 16](https://askubuntu.com/questions/886537/set-e-o-pipefail-not-working-on-bash-script-on-ubuntu-16)

So, my question is, how do I fix these scripts, or else make it such that invoking them with  makes them such that they work/run in a bash environment on Ubuntu?

Comment: OK I am confused are you running Cent-OS 16.04 or 18.04?

Comment: How do you run the scripts?

Comment: Which particular scripts are you having this issue with? I just looked at every script under 
vgp-assembly/mitoVGP/scripts/ and they all appear to have the shebang `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: Running under 18.04 LTS, not CentOS.  Started with <./mitoVGP [options] input_file>

Comment: Yes, I know the shebang states '#!/bin/bash', but the O/S (Ubuntu) doesn't actually run the script in bash, it goes back to dash.  This is my original question/problem.